# receive from non-chan type time.Duration

Tags: select, go, time

In [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/go-programming-model-context.html) is following example provided:

```
func LongRunningHandler(ctx context.Context) string {
        deadline, _ := ctx.Deadline()
        for {
                select {
                case <- time.Until(deadline).Truncate(100 * time.Millisecond):
                        return "Finished before timing out."
                default:
                        log.Print("hello!")
                        time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)
                }
        }
}
```

When I compile this code I get following error: `invalid operation: <-time.Until(deadline).Truncate(100 * time.Millisecond) (receive from non-chan type time.Duration)`

What is wrong with the code from the example?

Comment: What would you expect to happen when you try to receive from something that isn't a channel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<-` is for receiving from a Channel, for this neither `time.Until` or `Truncate` returns a channel.

In this case the error message is identifying the issue, but doesn't really tell what actually to do differently.

go DOES provide some time methods that do return channels. One of which is [`time.After`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#After)

```
select {
case m := <-c:
        handle(m)
case <-time.After(5 * time.Minute):
        fmt.Println("timed out")
}
```

---

I would highly recommend go by example and a tour of go.  They do an amazing job introducing channels and `for/select`

- https://gobyexample.com/channels
- https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2

Answer (score 1):

Use [`time.After`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#After)

```
func LongRunningHandler(ctx context.Context) string {
        deadline, _ := ctx.Deadline()
        for {
                select {
                case <- time.After(time.Until(deadline).Truncate(100 * time.Millisecond)):
                        return "Finished before timing out."
                default:
                        log.Print("hello!")
                        time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)
                }
        }
}
```